# Php Parse Error "For-Loop"

Tags: php, for-loop, parse-error

is it possible to do this? 
 here is my code and error:

```
for ($i=1; ; $i {
  if (is_numeric($row[$i])) { //Error Line
    $c .= ",".$row[$i];
  } else {
    $c .=",'".$row[$i]."'";
  }
}
$c.=")";
```

**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected T_IF in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot.....**

```
for ($i=1; ; $i) {
  if (is_numeric($row[$i])) {
    $c .= ",".$row[$i];
  } else {
    $c .=",'".$row[$i]."'"; // Error Line
  }
}
//$c.=")";
```

**Fatal error:** Allowed memory size of 12582912 bytes exhausted

I've Tried Everything I'd Appreciate If You Could Help.. 
Thanks..

Comment: `for ($i=1; ; $i {` You're missing a `)`. And how do both of those loops finish?

Comment: This `for ($i=1; ; $i)` should be `for ($i=1; $i < count($rows) ; $i++)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the manual for the [`for`](http://php.net/for) construct. You miss the second expression, used for terminating the loop. Also probably an incrementor.

What you probably ought to use is:

```
for ($i=1; isset($row[$i]); $i++) {
//              ^^           ^^ 
//           condition     counter
```

Usually arrays in PHP start with index `0` and not `1`. But we don't know the rest of your code, so.